# Building individual set elements from the set indices

Tags: python

Let's suppose that indices of array lst is a set. In the following program I'm printing all of the possible unique subsets for k=1,2,3 of array lst. As you can see there is a counter for each subset element. For instance element 23 has subset element ( 3 , 5 ). What I want to do is that by only having access to the counter, I want to be able to build the element, for instance if I have counter value as 23, I should be able to create (3,5). Obviously I want to do this without storing all of these possible combinations on memory. Can anyone help me out?

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

counter=0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print("counter:",counter,"(",i,")", end="\t")
    counter+=1
print()

for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(lst),1):
        print("counter:",counter,"(",i,",",j,")", end="\t")
        counter+=1
    print()


for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(lst),1):
        for k in range(j+1,len(lst),1):
            print("counter:",counter,"(",i,",",j,",",k,")", end="\t")
            counter+=1
    print()
```

Results:

```
counter: 0 ( 0 )    counter: 1 ( 1 )    counter: 2 ( 2 )    counter: 3 ( 3 )    counter: 4 ( 4 )    counter: 5 ( 5 )    counter: 6 ( 6 )    
counter: 7 ( 0 , 1 )    counter: 8 ( 0 , 2 )    counter: 9 ( 0 , 3 )    counter: 10 ( 0 , 4 )   counter: 11 ( 0 , 5 )   counter: 12 ( 0 , 6 )   
counter: 13 ( 1 , 2 )   counter: 14 ( 1 , 3 )   counter: 15 ( 1 , 4 )   counter: 16 ( 1 , 5 )   counter: 17 ( 1 , 6 )   
counter: 18 ( 2 , 3 )   counter: 19 ( 2 , 4 )   counter: 20 ( 2 , 5 )   counter: 21 ( 2 , 6 )   
counter: 22 ( 3 , 4 )   counter: 23 ( 3 , 5 )   counter: 24 ( 3 , 6 )   
counter: 25 ( 4 , 5 )   counter: 26 ( 4 , 6 )   
counter: 27 ( 5 , 6 )   

counter: 28 ( 0 , 1 , 2 )   counter: 29 ( 0 , 1 , 3 )   counter: 30 ( 0 , 1 , 4 )   counter: 31 ( 0 , 1 , 5 )   counter: 32 ( 0 , 1 , 6 )   counter: 33 ( 0 , 2 , 3 )   counter: 34 ( 0 , 2 , 4 )   counter: 35 ( 0 , 2 , 5 )   counter: 36 ( 0 , 2 , 6 )   counter: 37 ( 0 , 3 , 4 )   counter: 38 ( 0 , 3 , 5 )   counter: 39 ( 0 , 3 , 6 )   counter: 40 ( 0 , 4 , 5 )   counter: 41 ( 0 , 4 , 6 )   counter: 42 ( 0 , 5 , 6 )   
counter: 43 ( 1 , 2 , 3 )   counter: 44 ( 1 , 2 , 4 )   counter: 45 ( 1 , 2 , 5 )   counter: 46 ( 1 , 2 , 6 )   counter: 47 ( 1 , 3 , 4 )   counter: 48 ( 1 , 3 , 5 )   counter: 49 ( 1 , 3 , 6 )   counter: 50 ( 1 , 4 , 5 )   counter: 51 ( 1 , 4 , 6 )   counter: 52 ( 1 , 5 , 6 )   
counter: 53 ( 2 , 3 , 4 )   counter: 54 ( 2 , 3 , 5 )   counter: 55 ( 2 , 3 , 6 )   counter: 56 ( 2 , 4 , 5 )   counter: 57 ( 2 , 4 , 6 )   counter: 58 ( 2 , 5 , 6 )   
counter: 59 ( 3 , 4 , 5 )   counter: 60 ( 3 , 4 , 6 )   counter: 61 ( 3 , 5 , 6 )   
counter: 62 ( 4 , 5 , 6 )
```

Comment: Your code does not seem Java to me. Why do you use that tag?

Comment: language does not matter, I just want the answer. python is used, bcz everyone can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this definition of the powerset function:

```
def compress(it, n):
    for v in it:
        if n & 1:
            yield v
        n >>= 1

def powerset(s):
    return [compress(s, i) for i in range(1 << len(s))]
```

That enumerates the subsets in binary order.

Comment: I want this to be in O(1), e.g., have a way to create the elements without enumerating or storing all of the possible options. Because these are indices and in order, there has to be a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the complete answer, but only some hints to guide your reasoning. You can consider your indices as a twisted numeration system, where you don't have all digits for each numeration place.

Let `n = len(lst)` then the number of 1-index subsets is `n1 = n`, the number of 2-index subsets is `n2 = n*(n+1)//2 - n1` and the number of 3-index subsets is `n3 = n*(n+1)*(n+2)//8 - n2 - n1` and so on... In your example, n1 = 7, n2 = 21 and n3 = 35, and of course n1+n2+n3 = 63

So I guess that performing some variants of Euclidian decomposition, using combined // and % operators on `n1`, `n2` and `n3` should provide the correct subset. But that's not totally trivial...